# JavaScript function not called for all events

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and HTML programming and I couldn't fix this error. 
There's a function Getvalues() in Javascript code that runs fine for the first
text box with ID = sq1, whenever onchange event is called. More precisely, its only working for the textbox with id=sq1, e.g if I swap the ids, it works for that box. So basically I want it to work with all onchange events. As I am learning the basics, I would appreciate any help.

```js
<script  type="text/javascript">

  var b1,b2,b3 = 5;
  function Result(FLAG)
  {
   switch(FLAG)
   {
    case 0:
     alert("[Symbol=0]");
   }
  }
  function Test()
  {

   if(b1==0 && b2==0 && b3==0)
   {
    Result(0);     
   }        
   
  }

  function GetValues()
  {
   var temp = "";
   var temp2 =5;   
   for (var i=1; i<=9; i++)
   {
    temp = "sq"+i;    
    if (document.getElementById(temp).value != "" && document.getElementById(temp).value != null )
    {
     temp2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(temp).value);
     alert(temp2);    
    }
    if(temp2==0 || temp2==1)
    {
     switch(i)
     {
      case 1:         
       b1=temp2;       
      break;
      case 2:                 
       b2=temp2;
      break;
      case 3:         
       b3=temp2;
      break;     
     }
    Test();
    }
   }     
  }
</script>
```

```html
<HTML> 
 <TITLE>TEST Program</TITLE>
 <HEAD><h3 align="center">TEST Program</h3></HEAD>
 <BODY>    
  <FORM>
   <TABLE border= "1" align ="center" width = "30%" height="50%">
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="sq1" style= "font-size:50pt; text-align:center; width:100%; height:100%" onchange = "GetValues()" ></td> 

     <td><input type="text" id="sq2" style= "font-size:50pt; text-align:center; width:100%; height:100%" onchange = "Getvalues()" ></td> 

     <td><input type="text" id="sq3" style= "font-size:50pt; text-align:center; width:100%; height:100%"onchange = "Getvalues()" ></td>
    </tr>   
        
   </TABLE>
  </FORM>  
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Since you say you're just learning the basics, I'd suggest switching your reading material - whatever book or blog you're using appears to be outdated, just based on the capitalized elements and the deprecated table attributes. Also, you've got some invalid items, like your `title` being outside the `head`, and your `h3` being inside the `head` instead of the `body`.

Comment: I like to use books as my reference material than blogs or online content.
It would be very disappointing for you to know that I am learning using my notes made in my web engineering class. Guess my teacher is a orthodox. 
What book do you suggest for HTML and JavaScript.  I am not willing to use CSS or php atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onchange` event is calling Get**V**alues() for sq1, but Get**v**alues() for sq2 and sq3.

Answer (score 1):

Don Bottstein appears to be right, your GetValues() function is misspelled in some tags in your HTML.

An easier way to do this than attaching a function to each tag in the HTML would be event propagation.  That is, attach an event to the parent, then use an if statement to figure out if the thing being changed is an input, and call the GetValues() function on it then.

Something like;

```
<tr id="values"> //  Add an ID to the TR tag in the HTML

document.getElementById("values").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    //  e is the object that's triggering the event
    if (e.target.type === "text") {
            GetValues();
        }
    })
```